# Percentage of similarity between two colulmns

Tags: r, compare, col

Lets say I have two columns:

```
A  B
1  1
2  2
3  4
4  4
5  4
6  6
```

Is there a way to calculate the percentage of similarity, so that in example above we find that columns A and B are 67% the same.

Comment: Do you need `sum(df1$A %in% df1$B)/nrow(df1)`

Comment: 4/6 = 66.6% not 68% - unless i'm missing something?

Comment: yes you're right my mistake.

Comment: Is your comparison row-by-row, or just that the values have to be present in either column?

Comment: The comparison should be row-by-row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could take the `intersect` of elements in 'A' and 'B', get its `length` and divide by the `nrow` of 'df1'

```
paste0(round(100*length(intersect(df1$A, df1$B))/nrow(df1)), "%")
#[1] "67%"
```

---

If the comparison is between corresponding elements, use `==` instead of the `intersect`,`sum` the TRUE values from the logical output, divide by number of rows....

```
paste0(round(100*with(df1, sum(A==B))/nrow(df1)), "%")
#[1] "67%"
```

Or just use `mean`

```
paste0(round(100*with(df1, mean(A==B))), "%")
#[1] "67%"
```

NOTE: This is one of those examples where we get the same result by choosing any of the methods.